# How to downsample?

Tags: r

I would like to know how I can split rows 10 in 10, for example, I have this basics columns, DEPT and GRC1:

```
DEPT      GRC1
0       10,074
0,01    8,635
0,02    8,635
0,03    10,074
0,04    10,074
0,05    8,635
0,06    11,514
0,07    12,953
0,08    12,953
0,09    14,392
0,1     12,953
0,11    12,953
0,12    12,953
0,13    12,953
0,14    11,514
0,15    14,248
0,16    18,422
0,17    15,543
0,18    12,665
0,19    11,226
0,2     8,347
```

I would like to split and print like this:

```
DEPT    GRC1
0       10,074
0,1     12,953
0,2     8,347
```

Anybody have a suggestion? 
I can do it in Matlab whit the function downsample("file", 10), but I couldn't find one example in R.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "how I can split rows 10 in 10" what is that suppose to mean?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you only need `0` , `0,1` and `0,2` etc. So my guess is that you only need 1 value in the department or maximum of 2:

```
dat[grep("^\\d{1}$|,\\d{1}$",dat$DEPT),]
   DEPT   GRC1
1     0 10,074
11  0,1 12,953
21  0,2  8,347
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df[seq(from=1, to=nrow(df), by=10),]`

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, dec=',', text=
"DEPT      GRC1
0       10,074
0,01    8,635
0,02    8,635
0,03    10,074
0,04    10,074
0,05    8,635
0,06    11,514
0,07    12,953
0,08    12,953
0,09    14,392
0,1     12,953
0,11    12,953
0,12    12,953
0,13    12,953
0,14    11,514
0,15    14,248
0,16    18,422
0,17    15,543
0,18    12,665
0,19    11,226
0,2     8,347")
df[seq(from=1, to=nrow(df), by=10),]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following code:

```
df[df$DEPT == ceiling(df$DEPT * 10)/10, ]
```

The result:

```
   DEPT   GRC1
1   0.0 10.074
11  0.1 12.953
21  0.2  8.347
```

Used data as provided by @jogo.